# Braintree with Web Forms and data-encrypted-value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption, braintree

I am trying to use Braintree's API for payments on my side, and although they have excellent documentation, I am stuck when trying to receive the values from the form (not receiving any values from the fields at all).

The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Credit Card Number"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox data-encrypted-name="number" ID="CardNumberTextBox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="20" Width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="CVV"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="CVVTextbox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="4" Width="50" data-encrypted-name="cvv" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Expiration (MM/YYYY)"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="MonthTextbox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="2" data-encrypted-name="month" Width="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            / 
        <asp:TextBox ID="YearTextbox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="4" data-encrypted-name="year" Width="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="SubmitButton" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click"  runat="server" />
```

Since I have the main form in the master page, I modify its properties on page load:

Code-Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Form.Action = "./default.aspx"
        Form.Method = "POST"
        Form.ID = "braitree"


    End Sub

    Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim number As String = Request.Form("number").ToString
        Dim cvv As String = Request.Form("cvv").ToString
        Dim month As String = Request.Form("month").ToString
        Dim year As String = Request.Form("year").ToString

        Dim gateway As New Braintree.BraintreeGateway

        With gateway
            .Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX
            .PublicKey = "xxx"
            .PrivateKey = "xxx"
            .MerchantId = "xxx"
        End With

        Dim transactionRequest As New TransactionRequest

        With transactionRequest
            .Amount = 100D
            .CreditCard = New TransactionCreditCardRequest
            With .CreditCard
                .Number = number
                .CVV = cvv
                .ExpirationMonth = month
                .ExpirationYear = year
            End With
        End With

        Dim result As Result(Of Transaction) = gateway.Transaction.Sale(transactionRequest)

    End Sub
```

When I break at and expand the first `Request.Form`, I notice that it does **not** contain the `data-encrypted-name` values but the HTML-generated `name` values of `ID`.

**Note:** This also happens when I replace the `ASP` controls with `HTML` controls.

Is there anything that I am missing as to how it should receive the `data-encrypted-name`?

Comment: I work at Braintree. You didn't include enough of your HTML four us to see if you're using Braintree.js properly on the client side. Your best bet would be to [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) so they can help you. I'll also link your question to another similar question; see if it helps you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I Use Braintree.js With A .NET Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902211/can-i-use-braintree-js-with-a-net-web-application)

Comment: I see you already reached out to our support team. You should get another response from them soon.

Comment: @agf Yes, I just posted it here since it  might help more people. I managed to make the encryption work. I will post it here sometime later, and also send it to your support team just in case they need the extra info. Thank you for taking the time to reply

Comment: Great! Looking forward to seeing what worked.

Comment: hi anybody here please need jhelp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was simple, actually. It seems that some of my control where interfering with the `Request` object. After testing with an empty project to see that the problem was indeed on my side, I created a new master page.

By default, the form is wrapped around the `ContentPlaceholder` so I set the its attributes as instructed by Braintree's documentation, copied the javascript call and declarations below that, and in my `default.aspx`, the HTML is as follows:

```
        <p>
          <label>Card Number</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>CVV</label>
          <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
          <input type="text" size="2" data-encrypted-name="month" /> / <input type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="year" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click" runat="server"/>
```

Notice the `runat="server"` and `onserverclick` attributes on the `input`. I haven't actually tested this if it will work with normal asp control.

That works now, so I am moving to the tough part :)

EDIT: This works with asp controls also!

Comment: Would you mind linking to the documentation that you used? There's now both the older, deprecated docs and the v.zero docs. I'd like to be sure I'm referencing the right version in this context.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out. I used the older version, since at the time of writing, the v.zero was yet to be released.

Answer (score 0):

In c#

**using Braintree**

```
     (download liberary from: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/dotnet)
```

// Paste this code in page load

```
    string number = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["CardNumber"];
    string cvv = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["cvv"];
    string month = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["month"];
    string year = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["year"];
    string AmountPay = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["amount"];
    string rMsg = "";
    Boolean rBool;
    BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway();

    var _with1 = gateway;
    _with1.Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX;
    _with1.PublicKey = "xxx";
    _with1.PrivateKey = "xxx";
    _with1.MerchantId = "xxx";

    Decimal amount;
    amount = Convert.ToDecimal(AmountPay);
    TransactionRequest transactionRequest = new TransactionRequest();



    var _with3 = transactionRequest;
    _with3.Amount = amount;
    _with3.PaymentMethodNonce = "nonce-from-the-client";
    _with3.CreditCard = new TransactionCreditCardRequest();


    var with2 = with3.CreditCard;
    _with2.Number = number;
    _with2.CVV = cvv;
    _with2.ExpirationMonth = month;
    _with2.ExpirationYear = year;

    Result<Transaction> result = gateway.Transaction.Sale(transactionRequest);

    rMsg = result.Message;
    rBool = result.IsSuccess();
```